# Hide / show checkboxes in jquerymobile controlgroup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a `controlgroup` checkbox for jQueryMobile. I want to hide certain checkboxes depending on a previous selection of a `<select></select>`. However if it happens to be the last or first element of the control group, the checkbox border then looks weird. How would I get around this, and after the hide, have it show the control group properly?

http://jsfiddle.net/AyWN7/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line in both functions:

```
$('#appointmentAddonServicesFieldset').controlgroup('refresh');
```

Comment: WOW... awesome. I didn't even think of that! I didn't see a documentation page for `controlgroup` Thanks so much!